# Aggregate the long tail of a group by query into "others"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with one dimension and one metric:

```
name metric
A   4
A   9
B   27
C   9
D   6
```

I want to group by the dimension and then group the long tail of the results into an 'others' or 'the rest of the data' label.

For example my query should return all the names that the sum of their metrics are greater than 10 and group the rest into 'others':

```
name    metric
A       13
others  15
B       27
```

I can get this result by aggregating twice:

```sql
with T as ( 
  select 
    name
  , (case when sum(metric) > 10 then name else 'others' end) as group_name
  , sum(metric) as metric
  from MyData
  group by name
)

select 
  group_name as name
, sum(metric) as metric 
from T 
group by group_name
order by metric
```

Can I do this in a single operation without using sub queries?

[SQL Snippet](https://rextester.com/DFWP54026)

Comment: I really do not believe it because you need these two steps for calculation: First aggregation to check whether or not the sum is at least 10 and then aggregate the non-10 groups.

Furthermore your solution is quiet fast. What are your problems with it? Why do you want to remove the subqueries?

Comment: First I am curious if there is a better way, and second, in my real case I have many dimensions and metrics. I have to copy and paste many aggregate functions at least twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty certain this requires two levels of aggregation, because the original data doesn't have the information for grouping the names.  You need one aggregation to classify the names and one to calculate the final results.

That said, I would write this as:

```
select (case when sum_metric > 10 then name else 'others' end) as group_name,
       sum(sum_metric) as metric
from (select name, sum(metric) as sum_metric
      from mydata
      group by name
     ) t
group by group_name;
```

That said, you could use `select distinct` and window function for something inscrutable such as:

```
select distinct (case when sum(metric) > 10 then name else 'others' end),
       sum(sum(metric)) over (partition by (case when sum(metric) > 10 then name else 'others' end)) as metric
from mydata
group by name;
```

However, `select distinct` is really doing another aggregation.  So this eliminates the subquery but not the work.

Comment: What's the advantage of your first option over my query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nice solution! But please add a `)` for the partition clause :)

Comment: @homam . . . They are essentially the same.  I just prefer calculating the sum first and then using that calculation for the aggregation.  Your version requires repeating `sum(metric)`.